# Vector Geometry involving Minimum Values

Tags: vector-spaces

Find the minimum value of the function $f(x,y,z)=x+y+z^2$ along the straight line which contains the points $(-3,9,1)$ and $(-1,15,3)$.

A guideline on how to approach this type of question would be most helpful. This question has no relation to homework or the related; it's asked completely interest-driven.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers are your friend.  Should be able to look it up in Wikipedia or Wolfram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to parameterize the line and plug it into $f$ and then perform one-variable calculus on the resulting function.

In this case, the line is given by 
$$ (x(t),y(t),z(t)) = (-3,9,1) + t(2,6,2) = (-3+2t,9+6t,1+2t)$$
so you have
$$f(t) = f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = (-3+2t) + (9+6t) + (1+2t)^2 = 7 + 12t + 4t^2.$$
Solve for the $t$ giving the minimal value, then plug that $t$ back into the equation of the line to get the point on the line minimizing $f$.

---

Another approach is to geometrically reason that at the maximum point, $\nabla f$ will be perpendicular to any velocity vector of the line. The most convenient velocity vector is a difference between the two points, $(2,6,2)$, and $\nabla f = (1,1,2z)$, so the maximum is at the value of $z$ such that
$$ (1,1,2z)\cdot (2,6,2) = 0.$$
Plug $z$ back into an equation of the line to solve for $x$ and $y$.